# AngularJs - Can I open a popover on one element from another element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

New to Angular and Bootstrap and I've seen a lot about how you cannot programatically launch popovers, but is there a way that you can launch a popover for one element from another element. For example, clicking a button and having the popover launch on an image or search bar. Is this doable?

Comment: Yes that is doable

Comment: is there a problem with some jquery ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this example can help you with the popovers with angularjs, just study how it works --> [Popover Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ivankovachev/U4GLT/)

```
customDirectives.directive('customPopover', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<span>{{label}}</span>',
    link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
        scope.label = attrs.popoverLabel;
        $(el).popover({
            trigger: 'click',
            html: true,
            content: attrs.popoverHtml,
            placement: attrs.popoverPlacement
        });
    }
};
```

He uses a directive with **CustomComponents**

Comment: Your code is great for learning about directives and I've played with it quite a bit. But it's still a popover that happens on the element that created it. How would I click one element, and have the popover appear on a DIFFERENT element?